# Keyboard appears and as soon as disappears If I don't click 5 times textInput-react-native

Tags: react-native, keyboard, expo, react-navigation, textinput

here is some source code when i tap textInput,firstly, the keyboard disappears immeadiately, when i tap 4 or 5 times quickly it become normal. I could not find the solution. I dont know if it's because of the nested navigation, stack in stack or somethingelse.

```
<TextInput                       
  style={styles.searchinput}
  value={search}
  placeholder={filterSubject}
  clearButtonMode='while-editing'
  onChangeText={(text)=>searchFilter(text)}/>
```

Comment: Hi Faruk, The code snippet that you have embedded is not enough to answer this question. Please provide more context and try to describe the issue more. Also, it will be nice if you provide a screenshot or a recorded video.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.